# Error with word document after modifying with pathlib

Tags: python, filesystems, pathlib

This is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
doc_path = Path.home() / "word.docx"
doc_path.touch() 

with doc_path.open(mode="w", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    file.write("hello")
```

utf-8 is the default setting of word on my computer but whenever I try to open the document after having executed the code (which attempts to write the text "hello" in word) I get an error in word.
There is no issue with python syntax (as no error is raised in the python shell) but there might be an issue with the character encoding I used. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because you just write `hello`, which is not compatible with `docx` file. Try using `doc` file or write a right `docx` file.
If you want to write `docx` file, you can follow this example:

> pip install docx

```
from docx import *
document = opendocx("document.doc")
body = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body', namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]
body.append(paragraph('Appending this.'))
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615404/read-and-write-docx-file-with-python)

Comment: But the suffix for a word document is .docx not .doc

Comment: try using `docx` module to write `docx` file, it will work properly

Comment: Please elaborate, I am new to this. What is the docx module?